# How to use watir with children / xpath to click a button?

Tags: html, ruby, watir

I want to write a generic code to click on button.

So i get the class from a div. And the child element is the button. I access the child element with xpath.:

```
button = browser.div(class: /sp-m-cookies-container/).element(xpath: './*')

puts button.innertext # OUTPUT: Submit

button.click
```

Even though the OUTPUT is correct (it is the innerText from the button, the click has no effect. However, the below code works (where the button it's not generic).

```
browser.button(:text => 'Submit').click
```

What am I doing wrong?

In my case the name isn't "submit". It is often different. Only the class is always the same.

Chrome: 79.0.3945.130

Selenium: 3.141.0

Comment: Can you please share the HTML that you are working with? One possible reason is that `element(xpath: './*')` is not actually returning a button - eg it could be returning an element that is wrapping the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line as below.

```
button = browser.div(class: /sp-m-cookies-container/).button(xpath: './button').wait_until(timeout: 100, &:present?)
```

`element(xpath: './*')` is too generic which will return the first element irrespective of whether it's a button.

If you think normal click is working, then you can use the fire_event :onclick to trigger the click event as shown below.

```
button.fire_event :onclick
```